# Using uuencode, how to rename the file being attached while sending?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, uuencode

I am using uuencode as below

```
uuencode /root/some/directory/**Test.txt** /root/some/directory/**Test.txt** | mail -s 'test' xyz@mail.com
```

The above command is working as expected but while the mail comes to the inbox of xyz@mail.com the file name changes to **rootsomedirectoryTest.txt** but the actual file name is Test.txt

Filename remains same when i trigger this command from the directory where the file is.
above command adds path to the file name, but i need the orignal file name to be sent.

Could someone help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use

```
uencode /root/some/directory/Test.txt Test.txt | mail -s 'test' xyz@mail.com
```

Answer (score 2):

Do the work in the directory where the file lives, and don't specify the full pathame:

```
cd /root/some/directory
uuencode Test.txt Test.txt | mail -s 'test' xyz@mail.com
```

Comment: uencode /root/some/directory/Test.txt Test.txt | mail -s 'test' xyz@mail.com .... this works.